# react module has error Using removed Babel 5 option: base.optional

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am quite new to node/webpack/babel/react - and it's quite a mountain to climb!

I am tantalizingly close to having the module react-network-diagrams example working but not quite there.

Here is my install so far and the error I am getting below that.

```
node --version              v4.2.1
npm--version                2.14.7
made directory              react-network-diagrams
in that directory...
npm init
npm i webpack -S
npm i babel-loader babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react -S
vi .bablerc             -- { presets" : ["es2015", "react"] }
npm i react@^0.14.3 react-dom@^0.14.3 -S
npm install react-network-diagrams --save   -- ok this time
npm install         -- no errors
npm run start-website   -- error - not found
uploaded react-network-diagrams-master to same directory
webpack.examples.config.js -> webpack.config.js
npm run start-website → error :sh: 1: react-docgen: not found
npm i react-docgen --save       → ok
npm run start-website → error sh: 1: webpack-dev-server: not found
npm i webpack-dev-server --save     → ok
```

when I run the website script provided I get npm run start-website

```
> react-network-diagrams@0.6.0 start-website /home/ubuntu/react-network-diagram
> npm run docs && webpack-dev-server  --config webpack.examples.config.js


> react-network-diagrams@0.6.0 docs /home/ubuntu/react-network-diagram
> react-docgen src/ -x jsx -o examples/docs.json --pretty

http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/
webpack result is served from /
content is served from /home/ubuntu/react-network-diagram
Hash: b9d3cb12fbebca77886e
Version: webpack 1.13.0
Time: 3413ms
             Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
examples-bundle.js  1.52 kB       0  [emitted]  app
chunk    {0} examples-bundle.js (app) 28 bytes [rendered]
    [0] multi app 28 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]

ERROR in ./examples/modules/main.jsx
Module build failed: ReferenceError: [BABEL] /home/ubuntu/react-network-diagram/examples/modules/main.jsx: Using removed Babel 5 option: base.optional - Put the specific transforms you want in the `plugins` option
    at Logger.error (/home/ubuntu/react-network-diagram/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/logger.js:43:11)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/home/ubuntu/react-network-diagram/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:305:20)
    at OptionManager.init (/home/ubuntu/react-network-diagram/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:506:10)
    at File.initOptions (/home/ubuntu/react-network-diagram/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:243:89)
    at new File (/home/ubuntu/react-network-diagram/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:159:72)
    at Pipeline.transform (/home/ubuntu/react-network-diagram/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:49:16)
    at transpile (/home/ubuntu/react-network-diagram/node_modules/babel-loader/index.js:14:22)
    at Object.module.exports (/home/ubuntu/react-network-diagram/node_modules/babel-loader/index.js:88:12)
 @ multi app
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

Try as I might I cannot quite see where I have gone wrong.

Thanks Ian

Comment: Can you provide your webpack and Babel configuration (.babelrc)? It's very hard to say anything without that information.

Comment: Make sure you are using Babel 6 configuration conventions by the way. It changed a lot in Babel 5 -> 6 transition.